# Raspberry Pi Zero as boot keyboard USB gadget (libcomposite and macOS boot)

Tags: usb, boot, pi-zero-w, macos

Since I have exactly the same issue and no solution so far, please allow me to repost the question by Charlotte J at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1449796/raspberry-pi-zero-as-boot-keyboard-usb-gadget) again on this board:

I am trying to turn Raspberry Pi Zero W as a "boot compatible"
keyboard (USB gadget). I've followed [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/) to make it
work in OS, i.e. when plugged into a Mac computer that has been
powered on and logged into a user, I can send keystrokes via Raspberry
Pi to the Mac by running scripts writing bytes to the device file
(/dev/hidg0). The tutorial makes use of two modules: dwc2 and
libcomposite.

However, I need the Pi to work as a keyboard in Mac's EFI (BIOS).
Specifically, I want to send Command+R keystroke as the Mac is booting
up to enter the recovery mode.

[AlanT: My application would be to type in the user password to unlock rootFs encryption and let the macOS boot up to allow ssh login.]

Looking at [the official document](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf) from the USB org, boot keyboards
require support for SET_PROTOCOL and GET_PROTOCOL requests from the
host (Appendix B.1 and F.3). I did modify the report descriptor as
shown in Appendix B.1.

According to line 496 to 606 in [this class](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/6f84467f66ba847e643489a3d18b1cf81bad87d0/drivers/usb/gadget/function/f_hid.c) in Raspberry Pi Linux
source code, it seems like the module supports SET_PROTOCOL and
GET_PROTOCOL requests.

However, Pi as a keyboard gadget does not work in EFI; only in OS.

Does libcomposite not include f_hid.c class? If not, does anyone have
any insight into how to implement a boot keyboard gadget? I feel like
I am missing something.

Thank you very much in advance!

Fyi (this is the descriptor cited by [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1449796/raspberry-pi-zero-as-boot-keyboard-usb-gadget)):

[image]

PS: My current descriptor looks like this (from https://github.com/pikvm/kvmd/blob/master/kvmd/apps/otg/hid/keyboard.py):

```
KEYBOARD_HID = Hid(
    protocol=1,  # Keyboard protocol
    subclass=1,  # Boot interface subclass

    report_length=8,

    report_descriptor=bytes([
        # https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_hid.txt

        # Keyboard
        0x05, 0x01,  # USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
        0x09, 0x06,  # USAGE (Keyboard)
        0xA1, 0x01,  # COLLECTION (Application)

        # Modifiers
        0x05, 0x07,  # USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
        0x19, 0xE0,  # USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl)
        0x29, 0xE7,  # USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)
        0x15, 0x00,  # LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
        0x25, 0x01,  # LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
        0x75, 0x01,  # REPORT_SIZE (1)
        0x95, 0x08,  # REPORT_COUNT (8)
        0x81, 0x02,  # INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)

        # Reserved byte
        0x95, 0x01,  # REPORT_COUNT (1)
        0x75, 0x08,  # REPORT_SIZE (8)
        0x81, 0x03,  # INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)

        # LEDs output
        0x95, 0x05,  # REPORT_COUNT (5)
        0x75, 0x01,  # REPORT_SIZE (1)
        0x05, 0x08,  # USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
        0x19, 0x01,  # USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)
        0x29, 0x05,  # USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)
        0x91, 0x02,  # OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs)

        # Reserved 3 bits in output
        0x95, 0x01,  # REPORT_COUNT (1)
        0x75, 0x03,  # REPORT_SIZE (3)
        0x91, 0x03,  # OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)

        # 6 keys
        0x95, 0x06,  # REPORT_COUNT (6)
        0x75, 0x08,  # REPORT_SIZE (8)
        0x15, 0x00,  # LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
        0x25, 0x65,  # LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (101)
        0x05, 0x07,  # USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)
        0x19, 0x00,  # USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved)
        0x29, 0x65,  # USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application)
        0x81, 0x00,  # INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)

        0xC0,  # END_COLLECTION
    ]),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, power should not be a problem. The pi zero is connected over the PWR port to a power adapter. It is rather a problem with the boot protocol described above.

Comment: `The pi zero is connected over the PWR port to a power adapter. It is rather a problem` ... when you use OTG for the gadget it's a problem because OTG power your device trought USB

Comment: OK, I removed the power adapter from PWR. The zerow now gets power over OTG. After rebooting the host machine, I simply have to wait for the zerow to fully reboot. Still the keyboard function over OTG does not work on the Mac login screen.

Comment: What is your configuration ? Maybe follow this [good guide](https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383)

Comment: I am using the config_fs created by https://github.com/pikvm/docs - great project BTW... Which is based on the isticktoit guide you mentioned. Could you please repost your former replies? It has something to do with the boot keyboard protocol, I am quite sure...

Comment: ... Try to post your output of : 1 - find your device VID:PID `lsusb` , 2- get infos : `lsusb -v -d VIP:PID` ... (ho your on OSX sorry, can you do that on another Linux ?). EDIT : on OSX : `brew install lsusb`

Comment: The output of lsusb for the original Apple Keyboard is too long for a comment. Already copied idVendor, idProduct, iManufacturer and iProduct  to usb_gadget config, did not help.

Comment: `Still the keyboard function over OTG does not work on the Mac login screen` , 
are you sure you will wait as long as necessary?

Comment: `The output of lsusb for the original Apple Keyboard is too long for a comment` : You can edit your original question with your keyboard gadget conf , not your Apple keyboard

Comment: yes, waited long enough after reboot. pi is up and running. connecting with ssh to works fine. BTW: output of lsusb on macOS is very brief, not comparable to Linux, no useful details. and: I am not using an Arduino, only zerow

Comment: Ok. Then you can connect to the raspberry when the RPi is in gadget mode with ssh ? Try to see any errors message with `dmesg` or `syslog` at this time ?

Comment: What is your screenshot , your current descriptor ? because some values not match with the descriptor [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/)

Comment: please post the whole descriptor as text

Comment: @jsotola: Please find my current descriptor at the end of the question (after "PS:")